# Installing hachoir-metadata throws exception

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the package `hachoir-metadata` using `pip`:

> pip install hachoir-metadata

After executing the above command, I got the error

> C:\Users\Dimitar>pip install hachoir-metadata Downloading/unpacking
>   hachoir-metadata   Running setup.py
>   (path:C:\Users\Dimitar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Dimitar\h
>   achoir-metadata\setup.py) egg_info for package hachoir-metadata
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 17, in 
>         File "C:\Users\Dimitar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Dimitar\hachoir-metada
>   ta\setup.py", line 65
>           except OSError, err:
>                         ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 17, in
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dimitar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Dimitar\hachoir-metadata\s
>   etup.py", line 65
>
> ```
> except OSError, err:
>
>               ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The downloaded file is the correct one from Pypi. From the log:

> Using version 1.3.3 (newest of versions: 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3,
>   1.2.1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0.1, 1.0)
>   Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hachoir-metadata/hachoir-metadata-1.3.3.tar.gz#md5=26e04a2395205d31469fc2d6935055a9
>   (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/hachoir-metadata/)

I've opened the file hachoir-metadata\setup.py to see what's wrong on line 65:

```
    command = ["pyuic4", "-o", dialog_python, dialog + ".ui"]
    try:
        exitcode = call(command)
    except OSError, err:
        exitcode = 1
```

But the above lines can't tell me anything more since I'm using Python for 1 hour. My guess is that I'm missing some other packages, which needs to be installed prior installing this hachoir-metadata? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Python 3, but this package does not support it.

The line throwing the error is valid Python 2 syntax, but not valid Python 3 syntax.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have installed Python 3.4 so I must install Python 2.7

Comment: @DTs: If you'd like to use this package, yes.